# What does doFinal function do in creation of HMac in java

Tags: java, hmac

I have a hmac generation method in java which is defined as follows:-

```
String encStr = "POST\n" + timestamp + "\n" + message;
    Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA1");
    sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

    String hash = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(encStr.getBytes()));

    return hash;
```

where secret and function name is my private keys and name.
I just want to know what doFinal function does as the oracle documents say it is resetting the key but they have explicit reset method as well

Comment: You use the `Mac` object only once, so it does not matter if the key is reset or not. What specifically is your question?

Comment: My question is what is the use of doFinal method on hmac instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about when you have a large amount of data, you will do:

```
sha256_HMAC.init()
while(read more data into buffer) {
    sha256_HMAC.upadte(buffer)
}
result = sha256_HMAC.doFinal()
```

So, what `doFinal(buffer)` do is:

```
do `update(buffer)` 
calculate the cryptography result
reset the HmacSHA1 instance
return the cryptography result
```

The `doFinal` means this is the last(final) step to calculate the result, and there is no more data.

From Java document (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Mac.html):

- `byte[] doFinal()` Finishes the MAC operation.
- `byte[] doFinal(byte[] input)` Processes the given array of bytes and finishes the MAC operation.